# put .js content from file in wordpress head

Tags: javascript, wordpress, head, wordpress-plugin-creation

I want to load a .js file from my custom plugin into the  section of my wordpress installation. If I use the function file_get_contents and than echo this string output, it will be placed into body alltime. It should be placed in the head.

```
$headScript = new headScript();
$headScript->stipsHead();
```

My Head class

```
class headScript
{
    private string $scriptPath = 'assets/myFrontendScript.js';
    
    function stipsHead() {
        add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'getScript'));
    }

    function getScript() {
        wp_enqueue_script('js-file',BASE_PATH . $this->scriptPath);
    }
```

it should be in the head?. Same results come out with echo file_get_contents().

How I can put myFrontendScript.js in the header of my wordpress instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. You can let Wordpress handle the loading, if you use `wp_enqueue_script()`:

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'my_wp_enqueue_scripts' ], 100 );


    /**
     * Load the Javascript file
     */
    function my_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
        $theme             = wp_get_theme();
        $file_with_path = get_template_directory() . '/some/path/script.js';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts', $file_with_path, '', $theme->Version, false );
    }
```

Assuming the template that is in use, was developed "correctly" to the Wordpress standard, you should then see your script in the header.